# Flutter one account per device

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

How to make so that under one account came only one user in the application? I use flutter + firebase auth (email and passsword)
For example, I have an account and only I can log in from my device. if someone found out my account, he would not be able to log in
Thank you!

Comment: You can use device ID to track unique device against a specific account, so when a user tries to log in from new device, you can inform him another device is already on this account.

Comment: and how can this be implemented? using analytics?

Comment: No, you can use [device_info](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info)

Comment: so, I realized that with the help of device_info I will receive information about the device (including the device id), but I don’t quite understand how to link it to an account?

Comment: OK, I am just giving you very rough idea, once you have device info you may want to upload it in a node with device id as root and have account info as child.

Comment: I thought about your proposal and did not understand to this! It turns out I get the device id and username and send it to the database and manually control all of it there? If this name is repeated, will I delete it?

Comment: Yes, you got it a bit, if user tries to log in in the second phone, you will get a response (after fetching your database), that this user is already registered on another device, you can block the UI now in new phone.

Comment: Hey dude, could you provide an example please? If it doesn’t bother you)) my knowledge is not enough)

Comment: I need it very much

Comment: I am sorry, I can't get enough time to do this from scratch. But if you want I can provide you some steps as answer how to do it. There will be no code just steps. Will that work? I suggest you to have a look on Firebase cloud firestore before you start working on it. You may end up in implementing a bad design if you don't have enough knowledge on this which will eventually waste your time and money.

Comment: Well, let's try! better than nothing) thanks

Comment: This is how I do it - I use device_info and send three lines to the firestore (username, password, device name) when the user fills in the data and presses the enter button

in the right direction?

Comment: I added an answer, can you take a look into it. It is very rough idea that will help you.

Comment: use this https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus/example instead. The above as been discontinued

Answer (score 4):

I am just giving you an idea how to do it.

1. In cloud firestore, make a collection called `device_ids`.
2. When a user tries to log in, check if device ID (let's say `9876543210`) of his phone is present as document ID in your collection `device_ids`.
3. If no, create a document ID with this device ID and in this document ID, create a `email` field and put given email ID here and allow user to sign up.
4. If yes, go to the particular document ID (`9876543210` here) and fetch the `email` (which is `hello@email.com`). Now check if user entered this email, allow him to log in else tell him the fetched email ID is already registered for this device and he needs to sign in with email ID.

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: if I understand you correctly ... it turns out when I try to log in with any email address, first the program checks if the email address is in the firestore, if so, block ui, and if not, open access !?
I just want to know if I understood your logic correctly.)))

Comment: Yes, you understood it a bit. The logic would be to first check if device ID exist, if yes, check for email address linked with that ID, if user entered this email, allow access else block it.

Answer (score 0):

If are only looking to ensure that the uniqueness of the App , then use ***Phone Authentication with Firebase*** .

Phone Authentication will send an OTP to the entered phone number for verification and this can only be accessed by one device as phone numbers are unique.